# string parsing in python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I want to parse a string in python. Example string is four numeric values separated by white spaces. I want to parse and turn into them floating point values. The code I'm dealing is below. When I debug the code. It never enters into the else block? what's the missing point?

```
def stringToQuaternion(self, str):
        s = ''
        list = []
        for i in range (0, len(str)):
            if ( str[i] != string.whitespace ):
                s += str[i]
            else:
                list.append(float(s))
                s = ''
        return Quadro(list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"If it's hard, you're doing it wrong." ­—me

```
Quadro(*[float(x) for x in S.split()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `str[i]`, which is a single character, to `string.whitespace`, which consists of several characters.  This means `str[i]` and `string.whitespace` can never be equal.

You could use `str[i] in string.whitespace` or even better `str[i].isspace()` instead.

(As a side note, don't name a variable `str` in Python, since this will shadow the name of the built-in type.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `str[i] in string.whitespace` rather than `!=`. However, an explicit loop like this is not very Pythonic. Try this more idiomatic approach:

```
def stringToQuaternion(self, s):
    l = [float(w) for w in s.split()]
    return Quadro(l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3])
```

(It's best not to use `str` and `list` as variable names as those are built-in data types.)

The syntax `func(*l)` unpacks the items in a list `l` and passes them as individual arguments to a function. Even simpler, if a bit more cryptic:

```
def stringToQuaternion(self, s):
    return Quadro(*[float(w) for w in s.split()])
```